# Scheduled Task Launch Failure - 2147944309

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012

There is a scheduled task that executes a script. It was running fine until one day it started to fail with 'Task Scheduler failed to start "Task" task for user "domain account". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147944309.' It failed on a Friday, ran on a Saturday, then began failing daily after that. My research on this found that 2147944309 means the account is either disabled or locked out. I double checked the account and it was neither. Server is Windows 2012. It's an RDS server so it reboots every morning. After it reboots a warning message shows in history for the task "Task Scheduler did not launch task "Task" as it missed its schedule. Consider using the configuration option to start the task when available, if schedule is missed."

What I was able to determine:

- account is not locked or disabled
- account is in the administrator group on the server
- permissions are correct on the script
- set it to run with highest privileges
- able to manually kick off the task
- the task is in a folder under Task Scheduler Library
- created a test task to run notepad under the same account in the
  folder. It did not run
- created a test task in a test folder under Task Scheduler Library to
  run notepad under the same account. It did not run
- created a test task directly Task Scheduler Library to run notepad
  under the same account. It ran
- moved the task under directly under Task Scheduler Library. Ran for four days and the started erring.

The scheduled task kicked off for four days in a row and then began failing with the same error. Yesterday, I set the option to restart every minute three times if it fails. It didn't execute a second or third time after failing. Any ideas what the heck is going with this?

Comment: Have you confirmed the user has the ‘logon as a batch job’ permission? This is a group policy.

Comment: Would this permission only allow the task to run for a few days and then stop?

Comment: No. But something might have changed the permissions. Look in the security event log. It should tell you all you need to know. Look for audit failures.